# Create an Array with a dynamic Query in PL/pgSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, execute, plpgsql

I am trying to create an array with a dynamic select query in a plpgsql function. Unfortunately I get an syntax error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXECUTE"
ZEILE 19:  SELECT DISTINCT INTO outputIdsToDelete ARRAY( EXECUTE findA...
                                                         ^
```

Can somebody help me please?
Here is the function itself:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deleteMAPPINGs(
   mapTable1_key text, mapping_table text, mapTable2_key text,
   table2 text, table2_key text,
   inputIdsToDelete bigint[]) RETURNS bigint[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    outputIdsToDelete bigint[];
    findAllQuery text;
    findUnreferencedQuery text;
    BEGIN
    findAllQuery := 'SELECT DISTINCT ' || mapTable2_key ||
        ' FROM '  || mapping_table ||
        ' WHERE ' || mapTable1_key || ' = ANY(inputIdsToDelete)';
    findUnreferencedQuery := 'SELECT DISTINCT ' || table2_key || --find unused
        ' FROM ' || table2 ||
        ' WHERE ' || table2_key || ' NOT IN (' ||
            'SELECT DISTINCT ' || mapTable2_key || --all used
            ' FROM ' || mapping_table || ')';

    SELECT DISTINCT INTO outputIdsToDelete ARRAY( EXECUTE findAllQuery );

    DELETE FROM mapping_table WHERE 
        mapTable1_key = ANY(inputIdsToDelete) AND
        mapTable2_key = ANY(outputIdsToDelete);

    SELECT DISTINCT INTO outputIdsToDelete --overwrite with unused
        ARRAY(EXECUTE findUnreferencedQuery);

    RETURN outputIdsToDelete;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use EXECUTE inside SQL statement - EXECUTE is only plpgsql statement, so it cannot be inside SQL -

```
EXECUTE string INTO variable
```

Comment: I see, thanks. How do I create an array from an EXECUTE query than?

Comment: EXECUTE 'SELECT ARRAY(SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable)' INTO avar; or in your exampleL: EXECUTE 'SELECT ARRAY(' || findAllQuery || ')' INTO ...
Just note - you query is not vulnerable to sql injection - you should to use quote_ident functions for secure quoting of identifiers inside dynamic SQL

Comment: Many thanks again! This is working :). I thake it you mean my query **is** vulnarable to injections and I should rewrite it to `findAllQuery := 'SELECT DISTINCT ' || quote_ident(mapTable2_key) ||
        ' FROM '  || quote_ident(mapping_table) ||
        ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(mapTable1_key) || ' = ANY(inputIdsToDelete)';`? My only problem now is to bind my input array `inputIdsToDelete` into the select query. I get another  error like Error: Column inputIdsToDelete  does not exist. Should I open anoter question or can you help me here?

Comment: you can use a USAGE clause: - EXECUTE '..=ANY($1)' INTO ... USING array_variable - 
or string based solution: || ' = ANY(''' || inputIdsToDelete::text || ''')'